# MacVim unable to load settings from custom gvimrc or vimrc files

Tags: vim, macvim

Ok so I'm setting up MacVim on my new macbook with Yosemite, using a homebrew installation.

To start off with I have no ~/.vimrc or ~/.gvimrc files setup at all.

Also I'm already familiar with links on stackoverflow which have explained that the .gvimrc file settings are usually applied after the .vimrc settings

When I execute the following command directly in MacVim my color scheme is applied fine

```
:colorscheme twilight
```

However, when I add the following line to a newly created ~/.gvimrc file the colour scheme does not load when I restart MacVim

```
colorscheme twilight
```

Keep in mind that I have nothing else apart from this line in my .gvimrc file and I have not setup a .vimrc file. If I execute the following command in MacVim

```
:scriptnames
```

I get the following output (not all lines included for clarity):

```
1: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
...
14: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
...
20: ~/.gvimrc
```

You will noticed that MacVim thinks it has loaded the .gvimrc file. Anyone got any ideas why the color scheme won't load?

Comment: A: If you enter commands in `~/.gvimrc`, do they work? Try adding `echo "hello world"` for example. B: Where is the `twilight` colorscheme installed? Is it available in the path when `~/.gvimrc` is run?

Comment: C: You wrote `~/.gmvimrc`. Is it a typo or some special MacVim file?

Comment: Yep gmvimrc is just a typo made in this post will correct it

Comment: @JúdaRonén: I tried A and got no output. Regarding B, my color scheme is located in the `~/.vim/colors` folder. I know it's available because the command `:color twilight` works in MacVim

Comment: Rename your `~/.gvimrc` to `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @BenFranklin: So from A I guess `~/.gvimrc` isn’t run by your MacVim. Try to add `colorscheme twilight` into your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl: Yep I'd done that before but nevertheless I've tried it again; now I've only got `~/.vimrc` with just `colorscheme twilight` included and no `~/.gvimrc` but it still doesn't load the colour scheme.

Comment: @JúdaRonén: I've tried your suggestion indirectly by following the last suggestion by romainl, no luck

Comment: Interestingly I even put the sole command `echo "hello world"` into `~/.vimrc` (no .gvimrc file exists in this case) and did not get any output

Comment: I’m not familiar with MacVim, but in (g)Vim on Linux you can specify the location of `vimrc` using the `-u` option.

Comment: I did a test from the command line and ran `vim .vimrc`  and I could see it write out the echo I'd put into .vimrc. This tells me something funky is going on with the MacVim configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it looks like I've figured out what the problem is. The gvimrc and vimrc files were setup fine in the end, the problem is to do with what command you're supposed to execute to run MacVim

I came across the following link:

https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=138

It was post #6 which made me realise that I was possibly running MacVim in the wrong way. I'm figuring that initially I probably mistakenly ran the MacVim binary directly which according to that post is the incorrect way to do it. Of course because I was running MacVim from spotlight it was repeatedly rerunning the incorrect command.

Anyway, I ran the command `Vim -g` from the command line instead and it worked fine.

Comment: I tried what you said,  `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g myfilel.txt` but it still doesn't contain my .gvimrc customizations, just the .vimrc customizations.